# possible to disable $locationProvider and $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, location-provider, route-provider

Can I disable these fellas? I am using angular.js in asp.net mvc app, and I don't need angular to control anything related to address bar or the links...

Right now in html5 mode disabled (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)`) it adds hash and action method's name to the address-bar, for example: you go to `\Home\index`, it navigates and then address bar text changes into `Home\index#\index`. ain't that's annoying?

if I enable html5 mode it stops loading pages at all (except the initial). I try going from initialy loaded page to another - it changes the address-bar's text (without adding hashtag thing this time) but won't load the page itself. ain't that frustrating?

Comment: You disable them by not including either dependency in your `.config()` call.  Sounds like you have something misconfigured though if html5Mode isn't working for you.

Comment: its html5 mode disabled by default, right? But I want complete non-interference to the address-bar from angular services

Comment: Hi Agzam, have you had any luck on finding a sollution for this issue ?

Comment: Agreed; any luck on this? I'm have the same issue(s)

Answer (score 5):

A makeshift solution exists here [AngularJS 1.1.5 - automatically adding hash tag to URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350412/angularjs-1-1-5-automatically-adding-hash-tag-to-urls)

The answer explains the first step (as explained above, with the addition of the new hash-prefix)

```
yourApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

The first bit handles Angular interfering with your address-bar *visually*, but now clicking on any links doesn't function properly as (read: `history.pushState`)

So, the workaround, as pointed out by user @Kevin Beal is some variation of setting the `target` of the `<a>` to `_self`

```
$('a[href]').attr({'target':'_self'})
```

or on a case-by-case basis:

```
<a href="foo" target="_self">Foo</a>
<a href="http://some.external/bar" target="_blank">Bar</a>
```

Although, for the sake of convenience and sanity, I think it's combination of these.

#### Markup sans `target`

```
<a href="foo">Foo</a>
<a href="http://some.external/bar">Bar</a>
```

#### JS

```
// If `http` protocol present, assume external link
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr({'target':'_blank'});

// Otherwise, assume internal link
$('a:not([href^="http://"])').attr({'target':'_self'});
```

Worth noting that the above selectors *do* required jQuery proper.

Comment: This works but not a very elegant one. I'm struggling to find an elegant solution to this.

Comment: @Devin — Agreed. Please post your findings if/when you do.