# AngularJS: Remove the backslash in hashbang without enabling html5mode

Tags: angularjs

Given the template for our url `/foo` the HTML contains the following:

```
<a href="#bar" ng-click="myfunc()">Hello</a>
```

My expectation is that this would direct me to `/foo#bar`.  Instead, it leads me to `/foo#/bar`, which is a problem because I need to use the value bar.  Right now I am forcibly removing the slash to get the value bar, but it's awfully hacky.

I am aware this is due to $location and angularjs's routing mechanism.  The following link gives a solution which would normally clear this up: [AngularJS 1.1.5 - automatically adding hash tag to URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350412/angularjs-1-1-5-automatically-adding-hash-tag-to-urls).

However, enabling html5mode screws up the rest of our links, as it seems to assume we're using a single-page app, while we really aren't.  In fact, we aren't even doing routing through angularjs.

All I'm looking for is a way to remove the slash from the location's hash.  Is there a simpler solution to this issue?

Note: Bar may be the name of a tab within a page, or it may be a div you can scroll to.  I'd prefer to keep it as a simple "#" syntax for clarity to others working on the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, angular **does** assume that you're using a SPA, because angular is a framework for SPAs. As such, relative links are always handled as if they're going to a different ng-view, hence the added `/`.

I don't know if there is a way to turn off the angular router, but an alternative is `$location.hash()` and `$anchorScroll()`.

I would suggest the best way to do this is to put a function in scope (`rootScope` if you use anchors a lot) something like the following:

```
app.run( function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll){ 
  $rootScope.scrollTo = function(id){
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
  }
});
```

Then your html would look like this:

```
<a ng-click="anchorScroll('bar')">Hello</a>
```

Comment: That feels a little over the top to get a relatively small piece of functionality working.  Plus, the bar value may be a tab (I'll add this to the original question) and there may be multiple functions to use with ng-click.

Comment: Though it seems a small part of your own app, `$location` and its manipulation is a large part of the angularJS framework. You have chosen to use it differently than it is designed, so there is a lot to 'undo'. 

I'm not sure what you mean about the tabs - in the angular world, a tabbed view should be handled by a directive.

If you want to try something more drastic - try reading up on whether it's possible to disable the `$location` service. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611214/turn-off-url-manipulation-in-angularjs) is along the right lines.